# Problem with phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, phpmyadmin

When I go to the web page http://localhost/phpmyadmin, it shows

```
The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Apache error log is:

```
 [Tue Jun 14 16:35:47.699632 2016] [:error] [pid 14660] [client 192.168.0.101:44854] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477
```

Also inside phpmyadmin it's showing this error:

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Please help!

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-gettext

Comment: The problem still exists

Comment: what is a version of php? 
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php-mbstring php-gettext

Comment: Also inside the phpmyadmin its showing this error: "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." Is it something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 1):

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Cause: mismatch of database user. There are several ways to fix.
Execute the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

The phpmyadmin package contains the script to perform this operation for you, all it needs is a user with permissions. `sudo` is not required if you're logged in as root, of course.
It might be worth trying to drop the current phpmyadmin user.

or:
check in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php`

```
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='password'; // set current password between quotes ' '
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';
```